# Laravel routing white page

Tags: laravel, routes

I currently have problems with the routes.

`/admin` works great...but
`/admin/users` doesn't work

When I call the `admin/users`, I get a white page.

sorry for my bad English, I hope you can help me.

here is my web.php:

```
    <?php

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('/admin', 'DashboardController');
    Route::resource('/admin/users', 'UsersController');
});
```

my UsersController:

```
...
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.users.index');
    }

   ...
```

Comment: post the code in your `index` method on `UsersController`?

Comment: @MateusJunges that is what is shown currently ... supposedly

Answer (score 1):

Your resourceful routes are overlapping with each other.

When you create a resourceful route, it will create the following routes for each resourceful route. Using your admin route as an example will create the following...

GET  /admin

GET  /admin/create

POST /admin

GET /admin/{admin}

GET /admin/{admin}/edit

PUT/PATCH   /admin/{admin}

DELETE  /admin/{admin}

---

Your issue is the next resourceful route you create is using `/admin/users` which will overlap with the above routes, specifically `/admin/{admin}` which will try and load the `show` method on the `DashboardController`

---

You can use partial resource routes to probably fix your issue, something like

```
Route::resource('/admin', 'DashboardController')->except([
    'show'
]);
```

Assuming you never need to use the show route at `/admin/{admin}` but at this point it might be best to either a) remove the overlap by using something other than `/admin` and `/admin/users`, or b) just create the routes manually and ditch resourceful routes. Personally i'd ditch them, they cause more problems sometimes than they are worth.